# What is the initial value of an initialized Array in Javascript on different systems?

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer-7, undefined

I've been struggling for months with a JavaScript problem where I have an array with a few properties, and later some of these properties are checked to decide whether or not to show a message to the user.

Now this all goes well on most systems (especially more recent browsers) but not so much on some of my client's IE7 computers.

Now I just found out that somewhere in my code I initialize a new Array like below, but never actually set the value for 'done'

```
var qar=new Array('question_no','pos','done');
qar['question_no'] = 1234;
qar['pos'] = 1234; //dont mind these numbers
```

Later in some for loop I check:

```
//check if this question was already shown
if(qar['done'])
   continue; //stop here, don't show message
//set done to true, so that this question will not be shown again
qar['done'] = true;
window.alert('messaged!');
```

Again, what goes wrong is that **sometimes** (actually pretty often, but not always) the message is not shown at all in IE7.

Now for my question to you: I know that qar['done'] should be undefined right after initialization, which makes my code work fine (in Chrome etc), but could it be that somehow in IE7 this situation is handled differently? For example that qar['done'] is not undefined, but some random value and therefore is sometimes considered true accidentally? Or is that a stupid thing to think?

If this is not the problem, then I don't know what is..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try qar['done']==undefined alert('messaged');

Comment: @Jurgen: still have a doubt? I see a valid answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing this:

```
var qar=new Array('question_no','pos','done');
```

You are just creating array with indexes.

```
qar[0] will be 'question_no'
qar[1] will be 'pos'
qar[2] will be 'done'
```

in this case, qas['done'] will always be undefined.

Thats why its causing problems. You should either use javascript object instead of using an array.

But you can do something like this:

```
if(typeof qar['done'] === 'undefined'){
   qar['done'] = true;
   alert('messaged!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right, I used Array() the wrong way. But still, when I checked for 

if(qar['done'])
   continue; 

when qar['done'] was undefined, it did in fact **not** give the message, so the continue statement **was** carried out. So my question still stands: in IE7, could that undefined value be interpreted true for some reason?

Comment: There may be some other error that it isn't running that code. But I created a fiddle and it alerts for first time in internet explorer as well. jsfiddle.net/emphaticsunshine/axeYJ

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this:

```
var qar={};
qar['question_no'] = 1234;
qar['pos'] = 1234; //dont mind these numbers

//check if this question was already shown
if(!qar['done']) {
   //set done to true, so that this question will not be shown again
   qar['done'] = true;
   window.alert('messaged!');
}
```